# Error building release target with Growl framework included

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just addred Growl integration to an Xcode application.  The source compiles and runs correctly under the Debug target while testing.

When I try to build the Release target however, I get the following error and I'm not sure why, or whoe to resolve it.

```
Building target “EchowavesNotifier” of project “EchowavesNotifier” with configuration “Release” — (1 error)
    cd /src/echowaves-notifier-osx
    /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -strip-debug-symbols -resolve-src-symlinks /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/Growl.framework /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/build/Release/EchowavesNotifier.app/Contents/Frameworks
    strip: for architecture x86_64 object: /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl malformed object (unknown load command 5)
    pbxcp: warning: couldn't strip: /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/build/Release/EchowavesNotifier.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl: No such file or directory
    pbxcp: warning: couldn't strip: /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/build/Release/EchowavesNotifier.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl: No such file or directory
    pbxcp: warning: couldn't strip: /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/build/Release/EchowavesNotifier.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl: No such file or directory
    pbxcp: warning: couldn't strip: /src/echowaves-notifier-osx/build/Release/EchowavesNotifier.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl: No such file or directory
Build failed (1 error)
```

Is it some kind of 64-bit (x86_64) related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this recently when upgrading Growl, and several other groups have noted it (I found some traffic on the Unison.app list). What seems to be happening is some kind of mismatch at the link step, though I haven't been able to isolate it.

The solution I've found so far is to delete the entire build/ directory and rebuild (which is much more than just doing a "clean" in xcode). So far I have not seen the problem recur for any developer after performing that. Please let me know if this does or doesn't fix your problem, since I want to know whether I need to continue hunting solutions for this problem should it come back.

Comment: I did an `rm -rf build` from the command line, but still am getting the same error trying to build the Release target

Comment: Here's another work-around. http://forums.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21261 There is some belief that this is an xcode bug, and I recommend opening a radar to make sure Apple is tracking it.

Comment: interesting.  thanks for the link.

I'll try downloading the source and building it myself on Leopard.

I am indeed trying to build with Xcode 3.1.4 on Leopard.  I haven't tried building it on my 10.6 machine yet.

Comment: compiling Growl.framekwork from the Growl source on 10.5 with Xcode 3.1.4 did indeed fix the problem for me